# Sending a certificate

Tags: java, web-services, certificate

i have an existing java client code which calls an asmx webservice. However the asmx webservice is being deprovisioned and is migrating to a secure webservice(svc).
As far i can understand i have to change the endpoint url and https from http in the url.
and then recreate the client code using the new WSDL.

However i also have to send a certificate along with every request, can anyone help me on how to do that using java?
Let me know if you need more information.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the public key of the server you want to communicate in the client trust store. JDK provided [Keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html) can be used to import certificate into the truststore.

You have to specify the trust store details in the client VM. The following parameters have to bet set on the client VM to specify the trust store:

- **javax.net.ssl.trustStore** - The location of the trust store file which has the public keys of the servers it wants to communicate.
- **javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword** - The passowrd of the trust store.

**References:**

- [Java SSL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html)
- [Key Store Vs Trust Store](http://www.coderanch.com/t/134383/Security/keyStore-vs-trustStore)

Comment: The answer is unrelated to the OP.He is asking about client authentication `However i also have to send a certificate along with every request...`